# Custom Sharepoint 2007 search and it's results

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-crawler

Sorry if I will ask the question that already exists or just has easy solution, i'm just a new comer to Sharepoint.
The question relates to Sharepoint 2007 search engine.
I have a few crawled properties and correspond managed properties. I need to crawling all these properties, but without one property!
I have own xsl and I use own presentation of search results, but it so similar to native SP presentation. And there i use "Description" SP property (isn't mine), which show me all my properties (it's values), and it's ok, but i need to exclude only one property from the "Description" property in the search results.
Could you give me explanation of how to do this by the code (.NET) or maybe good advices and references?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is an appropriate SO question because of the programming aspect, but I wanted to point out that there is also a SharePoint-specific SE site too: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found out the solution. In the SP UI we can uncheck "Include values for this property in the search index" checkbox of crawl properties. And these properties will removed from search results in SP "Description" property. And it isn't hard to found out the way how to do this programmatically.
Thanks to all anyway.